# Pairing sockets

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, vector

I have a server program (works on all three major os systems), created in c++ which strives to connect two strangers for communication. My current model seems depreciated, and I am simply wondering if there is a better way to go about serving the clients.

-server receives connection request
-checks for ban
-starts thread for this socket

---

[the thread simply loops through these steps]

-confirm connection with partner (check manager)
-if unconnected request partner from manager class
-receive on my socket <- client sends keep alive packets every 2s or so
-on disconnect inform manager, and close thread.

---

[the manager class works like this]

-add socket: push_back on my vector of sockPairs
-request partner: find unconnected sockPair, if none exist create new sockPair, once connected, mark sockPair for removal, if already marked, remove it.
-remove socket: add flag to manager id of partner that I've disconnected
-check socket: check manager id for disconnection

---

I'm thinking a map would be much more efficient, however I'm not positive, as I've never worked with them, what else do you think I should change? I'm hoping to be able to serve 200 clients with this model, I'm really unsure if the current model could handle it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A thread per connection simply *does not* scale. You need to use a mechanism such as select(), poll(), epoll(), WSAAsyncSelect() or anything else that will let you query a set of sockets for events. Then you process each socket in order, and repeat.

Comment: Okay, I figured i'd have to go async sometime. How many connections do you suppose I could handle asynchronously with about 60KB/s up? Does the connection's speed even matter with my simple server?

Comment: With efficient code (aka no byte-at-a-time reads/writes, don't copy network data all the time, use an efficient polling mechanism) it's not hard to deal with a few K connections. 200 connections at 60 KB/s is slightly above 100 MBit, the network code should not be the bottleneck here.

Comment: Fantastic, If I were to upgrade my connection to my maximum connection speed, about 7mb/s <-(megabit) up, would I be able to serve a few thousand (easily hopefully)?

Comment: 2000 * 60 KB/sec is around a GBit, so no. CPU-wise you should be able to handle it, but the actual bandwidth will cost. Thread-based isn't scalable because of the large cost (execution context and associated memory) per connection. A more sane approach would be connection pools, maybe one thread per cpu/core and then distributing connections evenly. All of this is so tightly coupled to what your application does that there's no silver bullet that works for everything.

Comment: Oh! I don't need 60k per connection!!!! Honestly the amount of traffic per connection won't be more than 300 B/s!!

Comment: Sorry for the misleading post.